# How do you assign a global variable to a label in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to create a program in Visual Basic that requires the use of global variables. The code for assigning the global variables is;

```
Public Class G
    Public Shared Oil As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Myr As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Scrap As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Rotgrub As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Ratadrabic As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Remains As Integer = 0
Public Shared Cost As Integer = 0
End Class
```

The next form I open sets certain global variables to different values, like so;

```
Private Sub btnMemnarchMeatlovers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMemnarchMeatlovers.Click
    G.Myr = 2
    G.Rotgrub = 2
    G.Remains = 1
    G.Oil = 1
    Form3.Show()
End Sub
```

Form 3 is the problem. I currently have buttons to change the variables, then display the change, like so;

```
Private Sub btnOilMinus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOilMinus.Click
    If G.Oil > 0 Then
        G.Oil = G.Oil - 1
    End If
    lblOilValue.Text = G.Oil
End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub btnOilPlus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOilPlus.Click
    If G.Oil < 2 Then
        G.Oil = G.Oil + 1
    End If
    lblOilValue.Text = G.Oil
End Sub
```

The variable changes, and if the variables is, say, 2, the variable will display as 1 when btnOilMinus_Click is pressed, but I cannot display the change before I press the button. I have tried;

```
Public Class Form3
    lblOilValue.Text = G.Oil
    lblMyrValue.Text = G.Myr
    lblScrapValue.Text = G.Scrap
    lblRotgrubValue.Text = G.Rotgrub
    lblRatadrabicValue.Text = G.Ratadrabic
    lblRemainsValue.Text = G.Remains
```

But the G in G.Oil and others does not highlight, like the rest of the code does when written, and the lblOilValue.Text and others displays the error "Declaration Expected".

I have Visual Studio Community Edition 2017.

Comment: These are *statements*, not declarations, they can only appear in a Sub or Function.  They belong in `Sub New`, after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: How does that work, exactly? I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: High time to try it, you can't write effective vb.net code without knowing what constructors look like.  Type "Public Sub New" and press Enter.  Shazaam.

Comment: If you set this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark t correct. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new module called `GlobalVariables` or whatever you like.

**Cut** and **paste** the class `G` declaration code from your form1 into the module file in between the `Module` and `End Module` lines .. This but cut it from Form1

```
Public Class G
    Public Shared Oil As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Myr As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Scrap As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Rotgrub As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Ratadrabic As Integer = 0
    Public Shared Remains As Integer = 0
Public Shared Cost As Integer = 0
End Class
```

Comment: Wondering why a module. I have a class that looks similar and I use it all over my app without problems and it isn't in a module. Can you elaborate, please?